# Highcharts - Tooltip not displaying all series values on hover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

[image: GIF of the issue]

The intended behaviour here is to have the tooltip display all 7 the bar values for a specific yAxis entry.

Instead it's displaying the values dynamically for 3 to 7 of the bar values depending on where the cursor is located in the yAxis entry.

The tooltip definition:

```
tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            formatter: function () {
                var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>';
                $.each(this.points, function () {
                    s += '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + this.series.name + ': <b>' + section.convertVal(this.y) + '</b><br/>';
                });
                return s;
            },
            hideDelay: 50
        }
```

Display function that converts numeric values to sings:

```
section.convertVal = function (_intVal) {
    switch (_intVal) {
        case 1:
            return "N";
        case 2:
            return "S";
        case 3:
            return "T";
        case 4:
            return "E";
        default:
            return "S.O.";
    }
}
```

[Highchart definition here](https://pastebin.com/ayb9vB4M)

[Sample data here](https://pastebin.com/nhrGzrCS)

Comment: Since you dont provide any sample data or show what your `section.convertVal()` function does I am going to assume it is because maybe some of the values fail to be converted to `a friendly string` and there for do not show.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: I added the requested information to the question, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Looks fine in jsFiddle using latest highcharts library - https://jsfiddle.net/svoseq13/

Comment: Thanks @wergeld , that's a perfect replica of my intended functionality. I'll have to look into what else is at play in my environment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version of Highcharts (v6.0.3) solved the issue.

It appears this was a bug in v5.0.12.